# How exactly does module_load_include() load a file into the calling script?

Tags: 7

Here is the code:

```
function module_load_include($type, $module, $name = NULL) {
  static $files = array();

  if (!isset($name)) {
    $name = $module;
  }

  $key = $type . ':' . $module . ':' . $name;
  if (isset($files[$key])) {
    return $files[$key];
  }

  if (function_exists('drupal_get_path')) {
    $file = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', $module) . "/$name.$type";
    if (is_file($file)) {
      require_once $file;
      $files[$key] = $file;
      return $file;
    }
    else {
      $files[$key] = FALSE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

`module_load_include()` is just a function that calls `require_once` from within itself to load an external file. But it seems to me that `require_once` should load external file into `module_load_include()` and subsequently, this loaded file should disappear when `module_load_include()` goes out of scope. Somehow "magically" the external file is successfully loaded into the calling script(eg: a page callback function) that calls `module_load_include()`. I don't understand how this is achieved.

Comment: When a file is included, it stays included for the rest of the current PHP execution. This isn't a scope thing, nor even a Drupal thing. It's just how PHP works.

Comment: That's what I thought but my private experiment showed otherwise. I defined a `function load_file($file){if(is_file($file)){require_once $file}}` and inside `$file` I defined `$var1 = 'var1 value'`; But I couldn't read `$var1` from the main PHP script. I could only read `$var1` from within `load_file()`

Comment: I can't speak as to your test - it may have been how you structured the code inside the file. But as I said, once a file is included, it remains included for the rest of the current process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting confused on scope. There's no "file scope" in PHP. The `include`/`require` statements are pretty much the equivalent of dropping the code within the scope that it's called.

Per PHP's docs on the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable
>   scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available
>   at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
>   file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes
>   defined in the included file have the global scope.

If definitions in the included file are global. For example:

- `global $base_url;`
- `define('MYMODULE_CONST', 123);`
- `function mymodule_function() { }`

Then they are global until the script execution ends.

If definition is not global (e.g. `$var1 = 'var1 value';`) then it only remains within the scope of the `include` statement.

Comment: I get your points and they are exactly what I believe happens in PHP. My question is: How was `require_once` able to include it's target file into a global/main script where said file is used, even though `require_once` was called from within the function `module_load_include()` which in turn is called from the main script?

Comment: It depends on your specific example, but it depends on _when_ the `module_load_include()` was called. For example, if it was called the at the beginning .module file, in a `hook_boot()` invocation, etc. If it was called early enough, it could be available at all points execution in this "main script" you're referring to.